# MSAL redirect URI without HTTPS

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm using [MSAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to enable Azure users to log into my application and consume some Azure APIs.

Trying to register the application for my dev env which is local but not using http://localhost

According to Azure Portal, the redirect URIs

> Must start with "HTTPS" or "http://localhost"

My local dev env is served on http://my-app.test

Is there a way to use http://my-app.test instead of http://localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

As the limitation mentioned, you can't use `http://my-app.test` for the web application.

Not only `http://localhost`, but also `http://localhost:xxxx` is allowed, your option is to configure the app with them, not change the redirect URIs in the AD App.